# only echoing the last 4 things inserted into a MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

ive got this script that echos the information from a mysql database.
now it all works fine but i only want to echo the last 4 statements inserted

this is the script

```
               <?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("blog") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog") 
or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: First question: does the `blog` table contain a column that indicates when the record was inserted?

Comment: no, not yet, this is only a small challenge for me. i plan to make it more professional when ive got this working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify your mysql query (i assume that each entry as an ascending id):

```
SELECT * FROM blog
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

But this will get them in reverse order. If you want them in correct order you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM blog
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 4
) last_four
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an auto-incremented column as an id for each blog post, you could sort on the id in descending order. Use a query like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY your_id_column DESC LIMIT 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `blog` table has a column called `created`, which contains the post's creation date, this query should do what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 4
```

This will order your posts by the most recently created post (time-wise), and will only return the first 4 rows fetched from the table.

Comment: it's always better to sort by ID because if `created` is a date field, it's not necessarily unique. If there's a duplicate, mysql will randomly select which one to pull first.

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with the query, changing the query to something like:

```
select * from blog order by blog_id desc limit 4
```

you'll have to change `blog_id` to whatever you use.

Answer (score 1):

use this query which will order the records by ID in descending order and fetch only last 4 by using limit.

```
SELECT * FROM blog order by ID DESC LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict your SELECT using LIMIT and ORDER BY, but in order to help, we'd need to know a bit more about the database structure.  Can you provide the results of "DESCRIBE blog;"?

If your "id" field is set up with auto_increment, then it's a good bet that higher numbers of that field indicate more recent posts.  Showing output in reverse order ("ORDER BY id DESC") and restricting the number ("LIMIT 4") should be fairly straightforward.

```
  SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Check out the precise structure of the SELECT command at the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html).

Comment: id int(11)   No None AUTO_INCREMENT

             
 username varchar(64) latin1_swedish_ci  No None

Comment: dont know why it has been pasted like that

Comment: id int(11)   No None AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: username varchar(64) latin1_swedish_ci  No None

Comment: Okay, so we've confirmed that AUTO_INCREMENT is attached to your "id" column.  That's good.  It means the SELECT that I (and others) posted should work.  Give it a shot, and let us know how it goes.  If it doesn't do what you expect, then you might want to expand your question with details, like what the results were, and how they differed from what you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("blog") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blog` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4") or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr> <th>Name</th> <th>Age</th> </tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    echo "<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['id'];
    echo "</td><td>"; 
    echo $row['username'];
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
} 

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Just copy and paste the code. I believe the code will works good. Thanks